# How can i merge array with the same key's value

Tags: php, arrays

How can I merge an array like below, I want to merge tax_year by province_code

[Original Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZDsX.png)

How can I turn it into this

[Target Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EckU.png)

Please suggest me. Thanks (Sorry I can't paste my code)

Language is **PHP**.

Here is the text version https:// pastebin.com/FSnUR1je

I want to merge array depend on **Province Code**

Comment: What programming language? Give us some example code.

Comment: Can you insert the code as text?

Comment: Do you want the merged array to depend on the `province code` or the `province` or both?

Comment: Language is **PHP**.

Here is the text version [https://pastebin.com/FSnUR1je](https://pastebin.com/FSnUR1je).

I want to merge array depend on **Province Code**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most likely a better solution than this, but this will work for you

## Input

```
<?php
$data["0"]=["province_code"=>"1","province"=>"VT","total"=>1009,"total_amount"=>123456,"tax_year"=>"2018"];
$data["1"]=["province_code"=>"1","province"=>"VT","total"=>453,"total_amount"=>123456,"tax_year"=>"2017"];
$data["2"]=["province_code"=>"5","province"=>"SV","total"=>85,"total_amount"=>56789,"tax_year"=>"2018"];
$data["3"]=["province_code"=>"5","province"=>"SV","total"=>54,"total_amount"=>56789,"tax_year"=>"2017"];

$data2=[];
$codes=[];
foreach($data as $k=>$v){
    if(isset($codes[$v['province_code']])) $k=$codes[$v['province_code']];
    else $codes[$v['province_code']]=$k;
    $data2[$k]['province_code']=$v['province_code'];
    $data2[$k]['province']=$v['province'];
    $data2[$k]['total_'.$v['tax_year']]=$v['total'];
    $data2[$k]['total_amount_'.$v['tax_year']]=$v['total_amount'];
}

echo "<h2><pre>";
print_r($data2);
?>
```

## Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [province_code] => 1
            [province] => VT
            [total_2018] => 1009
            [total_amount_2018] => 123456
            [total_2017] => 453
            [total_amount_2017] => 123456
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [province_code] => 5
            [province] => SV
            [total_2018] => 85
            [total_amount_2018] => 56789
            [total_2017] => 54
            [total_amount_2017] => 56789
        )

)
```

Comment: Happy i could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would create an associative index:

```
$index = array();
foreach ($data as $v) {
    $indexkey = $v["province_code"];
    if (isset($index[$indexkey])) {
        $entry = $index[$indexkey]; // key already exists, will merge
    } else {
        $entry = array(
            "province" => $v["province"],
            "province_code" => $v["pronvince_code"]
        ); // key does not exist, create new and then merge
    }

    // merge here data
    $entry["total_" . $v["tax_year"]] = $v["total"];
    // ...

    // write entry back to the index
    $index[$indexkey] = $entry;
}
```

Finally you can convert it back to an numeric indexed array with foreach and array_push or left it as is.